# Vue.js - components data do not update

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Vue list that is based of an array and each array item renders a component where I bind the array item properties.

```
  <div v-for="item in items">
      <item v-bind:item="item"></item>
  </div>
```

This component has a mixed data, based on the binded properties

```
Vue.component('item', {
  template: '<p>ID: {{item.id}}, {{component_id}}</p>',
  props: ['item'],
  data: function() {
    return {
      component_id: this.item.id
    }
  }
});
```

The problem is that when I change the initial list array in any way, the mixed prop of the component maintains it's original update and does not change, even if the original binded data changes.

http://codepen.io/anything/pen/bgQBwQ

How can I make the component to update it's ow data property?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using a [computed property](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) in this case?

Comment: @UnholySheep YES! Thanks. I am really new to vuejs and I was not aware of the computed property, it works now. Thanks a ton! http://codepen.io/anything/pen/GrwNew

Comment: @UnholySheep, could you add your answer in order to vote it and help other people?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As requested in the form of an answer:

In this case a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) is the correct approach, leading to the following code:

```
Vue.component('item', {
  template: '<p>Original: {{item.id}}, Mixed: {{component_id}}, Computed: {{computed_id}}</p>',
  props: ['item'],
  computed: {
    computed_id: function() {
      return this.item.id;
    }
  }
});
```

This way the `computed_id` will be (correctly) recomputed every time the `item` prop changes.

Comment: This is correct, but now I have another question: if a certain property does not come from the parents data, how can I update a specific value and that to be maintained: http://codepen.io/anything/pen/vgQgeM This has a click event and it updates a value. That is updated for a specific items, but it remains when I have the array. Any thoughts?

Comment: @AdrianFlorescu I'm not 100% sure I understand what you are trying to achieve (and you should probably create a new question for it). If you want to combine a "component-local" variable (defined via `data`) with one from the prop you could just do that inside the computed one (rather than directly modifying the computed value) - e.g.: `computed_id: function() { return this.item.id + this.id; }` (where `this.id` would be a variable defined in the components `data` section). If this is not what you are aiming for you should probably create a new question.

Comment: I should create a new question, but to answer your question, please see the pen above and click on any row. The value updates, but when I change the array, I want that value to disappear. Not sure why that sicks on the exact same row even if you change the array.

Comment: @AdrianFlorescu In your pen the computed property is no longer connected to the prop in any way (you are accessing `this.id` rather than the props `this.item.id`) so there is nothing modifying the value of the property. And it sticks on the exact same row because of how Vue handles updates of rendered lists (in the background) - it does not recreate them from scratch, it reuses existing ones (see the [docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-for))